# Other ways of saying "except for one"

Tags: grammar, idioms

For example in the sentence

> All datapoints, except for one, lie on a line.

to me (not a native English speaker), the "except for one" part sounds too heavy. Are there other, lighter ways of saying this?

Is the following correct?

> All datapoints, less one, lie on a line.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can say

> All datapoints but one lie on a line.

Answer (score 8):

You could also just drop the 'for'.  All data points, except one, lie on a line.

Answer (score 7):

*All bar one* or *all save one* are possible, but Bill's *all but one* (which could also be expressed as *All but one datapoint lie on a line*) is most natural.